# Optimize slave .ibd tables, where slave has innodb_file_per_table and master does not

Tags: mysql, replication, innodb

We are trying to reclaim file space on our replication server. The space we want to reduce are `.ibd` files on the slave. We have a simple Master -> Slave (read only) replication setup, for some reason, we have innodb_file_per_table set up on the slave but not the master. So on the slave we have very large `.ibd` files, but not on the slave, of tables that have already been purged, but have not reduced in size.

Is there a way we can reduce those `.ibd`files on the slave with out dropping the db and re importing it?

Would running optimize table on the master reduce them?

Thanks

Comment: Unless I am misreading your question, you simply need to do `OPTIMIZE TABLE` on the _Slave_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `OPTIMIZE TABLE` on all the tables in the Master is a very bad idea. Why ???

Since the Master has [innodb_file_per_table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) disabled, running `OPTIMIZE TABLE` on all the table in the Master would make ibdata1 grow. I discussed this in my old StackOverflow post like 5 years ago : [Howto: Clean a mysql InnoDB storage engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927690/howto-clean-a-mysql-innodb-storage-engine/4056261#4056261)

> ## Can I run **`OPTIMIZE TABLE`** ?
>
> Unfortunately, running **`OPTIMIZE TABLE`** against an InnoDB
>   table stored in the shared table-space file `ibdata1` does two things:
>
> - Makes the table’s data and indexes contiguous inside `ibdata1`
> - Makes `ibdata1` grow because the contiguous data and index pages are **appended** to `ibdata1`

You could run `OPTIMIZE TABLE` on the Slave as follows:

```
OPTIMIZE_SCRIPT=/tmp/OptimizeInnoDBTables.sql
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpassword
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
SQL="SELECT CONCAT('OPTIMIZE TABLE ',table_schema,'.',table_name,';')"
SQL="${SQL} FROM information_schema.tables"
SQL="${SQL} WHERE engine='InnoDB' ORDER BY (data_length+index_length) DESC"
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"${SQL}" > ${OPTIMIZE_SCRIPT}
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} < ${OPTIMIZE_SCRIPT}
```

This will shrink every `.ibd` file. Again, *DO NOT RUN THIS ON THE MASTER !!!*

**GIVE IT A TRY !!!**

Comment: Running this command on the slave but not the Master will not "unsync" the slave with the master?

Comment: If it matters, replication is row based.

Comment: Not at all. The command OPTIMIZE TABLE would be effectively be `ALTER TABLE tblname ENGINE=InnoDB;` followed by `ANALYZE TABLE tblname;` for every InnoDB table. No data will be affected or lost. You do not have to run `STOP SLAVE;`. The SQL thread for replication will simply wait until a table it has to process is done with `OPTIMIZE TABLE`.